# dynamic dropdown displays nothing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I am trying to enable user select movies by title or by Actors (e.g in case that he forgot the movie name but remembered an actor/actress in that movie, he would be able to find movie by typing the actor name). I used jQuery auto-comlete to get movie names or actor names.

Below is what I have tried. The auto-complete parts works fine (i.e, when user choose moviebyTitle and start writing the title, the autocomplete suggestion works, also for actor names.

### Problem:

When user write the actor name, autocomplete works fine, Also a dynamic dropdown menu will be appeared, but the problem is that this **dropdown displays nothing** :| Could someone kindly help me find what is the problem with this code? Thanks,

```
<select id="selectType" name="source">
  <option value="">MoviesBy</option>
  <option value="byTitle">byTitle</option>
  <option value="byActor">byActor</option>
</select>

<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags">

<select id="movieImdbId" name="movieImdbId[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style="display: none;">  
</select>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
           //Create widget with default data source
           $("#tags").autocomplete({
               source: "actorsauto.php",
               minLength: 2
           });

           $("#selectType").change(function () {
               // Assign new data source like that :

               if ($(this).val() == "byTitle")
                   $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source", "filmsauto.php");
               else 
                if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){

                  $("#tags").autocomplete({
                  source: "actorsauto.php",
                  minLength: 2,
                  select: function (event, ui){
                    var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocom plete
                 // Here goes the ajax call.

                   $('#movieImdbId').show();
                   $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal, q2: $("#selectType").val()}, function (response){
                // response variable above will contain the option tags. Simply put in the dropdown.

                $("#movieImdbId").html(response);
              });
          }
        });
      }
    });
});

</script>
```

and here is the **actions.php:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']) && isset($_GET['q2']) && !empty($_GET['q2']) ){

$q = $_GET['q'];
$q2 = $_GET['q2'];

include('imdbConnection.php');
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieImdbId FROM movie_roleNames WHERE castName = :q");
$sql->execute(array(':q' => $q));

// Initialize a variable that you will send back to your ajax call, its still waiting for this script to be completed.
$html = "";

$results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($results as $row){

   $option = '<option value="' . $row['movieImdbId'] . '">' . $row['movieImdbId'] . '</option>';

$html .= $option;
}
echo $html; 
exit;
}

?>
```

### UPDATE:

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with PDO and `mysql_fetch_object` so that will break it. They do not mix at all together. scusi, ma è non bene Mona. Use its equivalent of `fetch()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: so html is rebuilt everytime the while loop iterates

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) You are right, I updated it, still not work :|

Comment: Are you checking for errors with `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`?

Comment: @mOna replace `$html = $option;`  with `$html.= $option;`

Comment: @RamSharma: yes, I did, still no change :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I used it in imdbConnection.php where I connect to DB

Comment: Did you try Ram's answer below?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, I exactly copied it.. :(  how can I be sure that q is really posted to actions.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysql` and `PDO` so try to use `PDO` instead of `mysql`.
You also need to add value in `$html` variable instead of overwrite value again and again.
change lower part of code like this because you are

```
$results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
while($results as $row){

   $option = '<option value="' . $row->movieImdbId . '">' . $row->movieImdbId . '</option>';

$html.= $option;
}
echo $html;
exit;
```

Comment: *"change lower part of code like this"* - Because of... [`?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427297/dynamic-dropdown-displays-nothing#comment41499551_26427297) - OP stands at making the same mistake again if not told why.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sir, I have added the because of

Comment: It seems that OP just changed the code in the question to `while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))` still no results apparently.

Comment: @RamSharma when I put $('#movieImdbId').show(); after the line "$.post("actions.php"....", it does nothing (It does not show even an empty dropdown)

Comment: did you try to alert the response?

Comment: sorry, but what does it mean? (alert the response)

Comment: look into your html/js code `$("#movieImdbId").html(response);`. just use `alert(response)` before it to check the response of your php code.

Comment: @RamSharma, I just run php actions.php and I see I have this error: 'PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_AS in /var/www/actions.php on line 26'   where line 26 is this: while($results as $row){

Comment: @m0na, please share your code because as per comments it's not matching your code

Comment: @RamSharma I shared both html/js and PHP file.. which file do you mean? :p

Comment: @RamSharma: I just updated my question, please kindly see the actions.php part,

Comment: change your while loop code with `$option = '<option value="' . $row->movieImdbId . '">' . $row->movieImdbId . '</option>';`

Comment: @RamSharma: I tried with both: $option = '<option value="' . $row->movieImdbId . '">' . $row->movieImdbId . '</option>';  and also:   $option = '<option value="' . $row['movieImdbId'] . '">' . $row['movieImdbId'] . '</option>';  but nothing is diplayed in dropdown!!!

Comment: @mOna the code which I pasted is right, now access page where you are using ajax

Comment: @RamSharma: but why I get this error every time that I run actions.php?   this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_AS in /var/www/actions.php on line 26    (Line 26 is while($results as $row){ ..)

Comment: @RamSharma: I think the problem is not about the php code.. but in html/js where I use ajax call.. Do you have any idea ? should I add or change something there? :|